# StopIteration error? During web-scraping of imdb page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to WebScrape the url = 'http://m.imdb.com/feature/bornondate' for the name of the 10 celebrities shown on that page. However Python is saying StopIteration and not printing my results.

Here is my code I think it explains what I am trying to do.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://m.imdb.com/feature/bornondate'

test_url = urllib2.urlopen(url)
readHtml = test_url.read()
test_url.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(readHtml)
# Using it track the number of Celebrities
count = 0
# Fetching the value present within tag results
celebrities = soup.findChildren('section', 'posters list')
# Changing the celebrity into an iterator
itercelebrity = iter(celebrities[0].findChildren('a'))
# Skipping the first value of the iterator as it does have the required info
next(itercelebrity)

# Finding a in itercelebrity. Every a tag contains information of a celebrity
for a in itercelebrity:

    celebrity = tr.findChildren('div', 'label')
    name = celebrity[0].find('span', 'title').contents[0]

    print '*******************************IMDB CELEBRITYS***********************************'
    # Printing the Name of the celebrity
    print 'Name --> ' + name
```

Here is the output (it is not printing out anything)

```
Patricks-MacBook-Pro:~ Patrick$ python /Users/Patrick/Desktop/IMDB_BornToday_Scraping.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Patrick/Desktop/IMDB_BornToday_Scraping.py", line 20, in <module>
    next(itercelebrity)
StopIteration
Patricks-MacBook-Pro:~ Patrick$
```

If you can't tell by now I am quite new to this :)
Here is the relevant html I am trying to get at

```
<section class="posters list">
<h1>March 7</h1>

<a href="/name/nm0186505/" class="poster "><img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTA2NjEyMTY4MTVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDQ5NDAzNDc@._V1._CR0,0,1369,2019_SX40_SY59.jpg" style="background:url('http://i.media-imdb.com/images/mobile/people-40x59-fade.png')" width="40" height="59"><div class="label"><span class="title">Bryan Cranston</span><div class="detail">Actor, "Ozymandias"</div></div></a><a href="/name/nm0696059/" class="poster "><img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNjUxNjcxMjE4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDk4NjA2MzE@._V1._CR156,0,1736,2560_SX40_SY59.jpg" style="background:url('http://i.media-imdb.com/images/mobile/people-40x59-fade.png')" width="40" height="59"><div class="label"><span class="title">Laura Prepon</span><div class="detail">Actress, "Karla"</div></div></a><a href="/name/nm0001838/" class="poster "><img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ4MzM1MDAwMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTU4NzQwMw@@._V1._CR5,0,271,400_SX40_SY59.jpg" style="background:url('http://i.media-imdb.com/images/mobile/people-40x59-fade.png')" width="40" height="59"><div class="label"><span class="title">Rachel Weisz</span><div class="detail">Actress, "The Mummy"</div></div></a><a href="/name/nm0765597/" class="poster "><img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE0Mjg0NzE2Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDE1MTkxMw@@._V1._CR19,0,271,400_SX40_SY59.jpg" style="background:url('http://i.media-imdb.com/images/mobile/people-40x59-fade.png')" width="40" height="59"><div class="label"><span class="title">Peter Sarsgaard</span><div class="detail">Actor, "Jarhead"</div></div></a><a href="/name/nm0278979/" class="poster "><img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMyOTYzODQ5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjE3MDgzMQ@@._V1._CR24,0,271,400_SX40_SY59.jpg" style="background:url('http://i.media-imdb.com/images/mobile/people-40x59-fade.png')" width="40" height="59"><div class="label"><span class="title">Jenna Fischer</span><div class="detail">Actress, "Blades of Glory"</div></div></a><a href="/name/nm0614220/" class="poster "><img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzE2OTAwNzM0Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzE1MDg0Mw@@._V1._CR26,0,488,720_SX40_SY59.jpg" style="background:url('http://i.media-imdb.com/images/mobile/people-40x59-fade.png')" width="40" height="59"><div class="label"><span class="title">Donna Murphy</span><div class="detail">Actress, "Tangled"</div></div></a><a href="/name/nm0862328/" class="poster "><img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTI0OTMzMzE0N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjI1MzYyMQ@@._V1._CR33,0,235,346_SX40_SY59.jpg" style="background:url('http://i.media-imdb.com/images/mobile/people-40x59-fade.png')" width="40" height="59"><div class="label"><span class="title">T.J. Thyne</span><div class="detail">Actor, "How the Grinch Stole Christmas"</div></div></a><a href="/name/nm0001334/" class="poster "><img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNzczODkyNzY4OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTU0NjQzMQ@@._V1._CR41,0,368,543_SX40_SY59.jpg" style="background:url('http://i.media-imdb.com/images/mobile/people-40x59-fade.png')" width="40" height="59"><div class="label"><span class="title">John Heard</span><div class="detail">Actor, "Home Alone"</div></div></a><a href="/name/nm1017524/" class="poster "><img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4MjU2MzA2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTIxMjc4MjE@._V1._CR0,0,3644,5375_SX40_SY59.jpg" style="background:url('http://i.media-imdb.com/images/mobile/people-40x59-fade.png')" width="40" height="59"><div class="label"><span class="title">Audrey Marie Anderson</span><div class="detail">Actress, "Beerfest"</div></div></a><a href="/name/nm0891216/" class="poster "><img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQyOTc5NzA0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwODQ2MjYz._V1._CR0,0,266,392_SX40_SY59.jpg" style="background:url('http://i.media-imdb.com/images/mobile/people-40x59-fade.png')" width="40" height="59"><div class="label"><span class="title">Matthew Vaughn</span><div class="detail">Producer, "Kick-Ass"</div></div></a><div class="paginator"><a class="next" data-start="10" href="#page10">Show more...</a><a class="seeAll" href="#showAll">See all</a></div></section>
```

Comment: It seems like The section's contents are not there to be extracted. They are loaded by an AJAX request  as show by @Dan D.

Answer (score 1):

The error results from:

```
celebrities[0].findChildren('a')
```

Having no results which then causes the iterator to be the same as if you did:

```
it = iter([])
next(it)
```

Which results in the same exception:

```
>>> it = iter([])
>>> next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

---

A better way to do it is with CSS selectors using the `soup.select()` method. This would print all the names

```
for name in soup.select("section.posters.list a.poster div.label span.title"):
    print name.string
```

would print all the names. The selector is perhaps overly specific.

---

But that doesn't work and I've figured out why. Look at the HTML returned from fetching the page:

```
<section class="posters list">
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
<span class="loading"></span>
</section>
```

The `section`'s contents are not there to be extracted. They are loaded by an AJAX request. That is issued from:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pagination = $('section.posters').itemPagination(10)
    var now = new Date();

    var client = new IMDbClient();
    client.useSessionCache(true);
    client.call('/feature/bornondate_json?today='+now.toYYYYMMDD(), function(data) {
        pagination(data.list);
    });
    var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
    $('section.posters > h1').html( months[now.getMonth()] + ' ' + now.getDate() );
});
</script>
```

The best option if you want to extract the data is to use a browser driver such as [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: I will add the html code to the question can you tell me what to do to make it do what I want? ie print out the celebrities names?

Comment: is it something to do with the class="posters list" having a space character? becuase when I hover over it in chrome it says section.posters.list

Comment: if I take out next(itercelebrity) it compiles? and no error is there but it does not print out the names....

Comment: Im sorry could you try it on your end it still will not print anything out :(

Comment: It seems Beautifulsoup cannot execute javascript so i will use selenium.

Comment: No need to use Selenium; why not jus drive the JSON API directly from Python?

Comment: I am a novice :( can you explain what that entails?